# Symfony: How to convert binary file response to Uploded File Object

Tags: php, api, symfony, symfony5.4

I'm getting binary response from third party API via `HTTP CLIENT` in `Symfony`

How to convert that response to a `UplodedFile` Object.

Please suggest a good way to do this.

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php), seems like you can instantiate it yourself. I think you need to set `test` to `true` however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `UploadedFile` class, since that requires a file path and will throw an error (on `move`) if you try to pass it a path to a file that wasn't uploaded via the $_FILES array.

Alternatively, you can use Symfony's `File` class (`UploadedFile` extends `File`), but that also requires a file path. So you'll need to convert the response to a (temporary) file, for example using the class below.

Since this class extends `File`, you can validate instances of it using the Symfony Validator and call `move` on it, just as you would with an `UploadedFile`.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

class TmpFile extends File {

    private $handle;

    public function __construct(string $contents)
    {
        $this->handle = tmpfile();
        fwrite($this->handle, $contents);
        
        parent::__construct(stream_get_meta_data($this->handle)['uri']);
    }

}
```

And use it like this:
`$tmpFile = new TmpFile((string) $response->getContent());`